# access function only though link using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

im having a small system where there is an link to activate or deacctivate the users..

so i have my function which lists down the users

```
function users()
{
//the code
}
```

and there is a function that takes the 3rd uri segment which is the id and sets the user as activated or deactivate.

```
function action_settings()
{
// the code
}
```

i want to make sure that the action_settings is accessed only through the function users and not allow any users to directly access that function.

so the link

```
localhost/motivators/action_settings/25
```

must be accessible only through the link from

```
localhost/motivators/users/
```

is it possible implement this restriction in Codeigniter?

Comment: is function users in the same controller as action_settings?

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan yep.. both are in the same controller

Comment: Have you tried the referer implementation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inside function action_settings():

```
function action_settings(){

 if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://localhost/motivators/users'){
  //wrong referer
  exit();
 }

 //activate user
}
```

It could also be:

```
function action_settings(){

 if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != base_url() . 'motivators/users'){
  //wrong referer
  exit();
 }

 //activate user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is that to supply the `uri->uri_string` as an argument to your `action_string` function (method) and parse it to check if it contains `motivators/users/` or just `users` then continue with `action_string` process. otherwise, don't.